# Prove that all the negative term of Laurent series is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

If the Laurent series has isolated singularity $z_0 = 0$. Prove that all the negative term of Laurent series is 0.

Can someone show me how to prove this problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is your opinion on $f(z) = z^{-1}?$

Comment: Do you mean removable singularity? Whats the expansion of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ at $0$?

Comment: yeah, I mean the removable singularity. and it is just 1/z ?